# Missing 3rd party dependencies on Github that are resolved correctly on computer

Tags: github, hosting

I'm moving a website off Weebly to host on Github.

I downloaded the website as a zip from Weebly. Opening it on my computer, it looks perfect. When I upload it on Github, I see that it's missing several sources:

- cdn2.editmysite.com
- fonts.googleapis.com
- fonts.gstatic.com

The sources are still referenced in the HTML, but I don't see it show up in the Chrome development tool. I see the development tool list "(no domain)" as a source instead. Ajax.googleapis.com is referenced correctly as a source.

What is going on to make the exact same code behave differently when it's hosted on Github vs when it's in repo on my computer?

Here's the Github repo: github.com/robbyhowell/robbyhowell.github.io

Here's Github page live: robbyhowell.github.io

Here's how it should look: www.elementaltheory.net

Comment: If I download the github repo as a zip, it gets the dependencies right again. This is the strangest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by mix-content blocks. Github defaults to using https. I had scripts in http.